# Do system calls call themselves?

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel, system-calls

Do they? for example, I was thinking of the simple system call `chown`.
Does it call other system calls like `read` and `write`? How can we find out?

Answer (score 2):

Sort of.

Kernel (e.g. Linux) has own internal system call interface, so one system call can usually call other system call, without need to setup the entire system call procedure.

How to find out? You have the kernel sources, you have probably `grep`, so you could find out.

Comment: or truss/strace the first command/call...

Comment: @JeffSchaller: How's strace going to show you subsequent internal calls? AFAIK, strace only shows system calls from userspace to kernel. If you can also trace internal calls, I'd like to know how.

Comment: @JeffSchaller: Exactly. I use strace for my tracing purposes. and as said, it doesn't give me the internal calls

Comment: `perf` can show you stack traces that include the internal kernel calls

Comment: good point, @dirkt - I was stuck in userspace :)

Comment: You can easily trace system calls with LTTng. This'll show you that system call entry-exit pairs are never nested.

Although the kernel never re-enters the system call dispatch routine as part of its system call resolution, it can certainly call or jump internally, setting up the stack as required (I think).

Answer (score 0):

Yes they do. For example the `fork` system call actually calls the `clone` system call. We can also use the `clone` system call for finer control over the child process.

Comment: No, the fork() syscall doesn't call the clone() syscall. No syscall is calling another syscall, which doesn't even make sense. What's probably confusing you is that glibc (ie. the *userland* C library) now implements the fork() function as a wrapper around the clone() not the fork() system call, which is clearly showing when strace-ing or debugging a program (`fork() = clone(CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD)`)

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. The old `fork()` syscall doesn't call `clone()`. The the glibc wrapper function `fork()` calls the syscall : `clone()`. Thanks @mosvy for pointing that out.